# Should I use an external jQuery instead of the one given in Wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm confused as to what I should do regarding jQuery and Wordpress (and also Bootstrap, kind of). I read [this article](https://pippinsplugins.com/why-loading-your-own-jquery-is-irresponsible/) on why I shouldn't be loading my own jQuery because Wordpress already has it and loading another can cause a mess of problems. But here's a real example. I *had* to load jQuery version 2.1.0 in order to use my function below (it wasn't working otherwise; it actually is only half working because it's supposed to be a file input where you can either click to choose a file or drag and drop a file to upload, but the clicking to add a file doesn't bring up the image preview). I had to use this version because the version that comes with Wordpress wasn't doing the job. Is that enough of a reason to justify? Or is there a way to make my function work without having to reference v. 2.1.0? Is there any harm in loading another version of jQuery nowadays? The article was written in 2013.

In addition, I am using Bootstrap to make a child theme and will be making a plugin as well. Is there any conflict with using Bootstrap to make a child theme and plugin? My rookie opinion is to make everything work with what is already given in Wordpress, but I'd like to hear some more experienced people.

**functions.php**

```
<?php

function my_scripts() {
wp_register_script('jquery1', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js', false, null);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.5', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-js.js');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts');

function my_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles');



?>
```

**JS**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#drop').click(function(){
        console.log('click');
        $('#fileBox').trigger('click');
    });
    //Remove item
    $('.fileCont span').click(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
if (window.FileReader) {
    var drop;
    addEventHandler(window, 'load', function () {
        var status = document.getElementById('status');
        drop = document.getElementById('drop');
        var list = document.getElementById('list');

        function cancel(e) {
            if (e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            return false;
        }

        // Tells the browser that we *can* drop on this target
        addEventHandler(drop, 'dragover', cancel);
        addEventHandler(drop, 'dragenter', cancel);

        addEventHandler(drop, 'drop', function (e) {
            e = e || window.event; // get window.event if e argument missing (in IE)   
            if (e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault();
            } // stops the browser from redirecting off to the image.

            var dt = e.dataTransfer;
            var files = dt.files;
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                var reader = new FileReader();

                //attach event handlers here...

                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                addEventHandler(reader, 'loadend', function (e, file) {
                    var bin = this.result;
                    var fileCont = document.createElement('div');
                    fileCont.className = "fileCont";
                    list.appendChild(fileCont);

                    var fileNumber = list.getElementsByTagName('img').length + 1;
                    status.innerHTML = fileNumber < files.length ? 'Loaded 100% of file ' + fileNumber + ' of ' + files.length + '...' : 'Done loading. processed ' + fileNumber + ' files.';

                    var img = document.createElement("img");
                    img.file = file;
                    img.src = bin;
                    img.className = "thumb";
                    fileCont.appendChild(img);

                    var newFile = document.createElement('div');
                    newFile.innerHTML = file.name;
                    newFile.className = "fileName";
                    fileCont.appendChild(newFile);

                    var fileSize = document.createElement('div');
                    fileSize.className = "fileSize";
                    fileSize.innerHTML = Math.round(file.size/1024) + ' KB';
                    fileCont.appendChild(fileSize);

                    var progress = document.createElement('div');
                    progress.className = "progress";
                    progress.innerHTML = '<div aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="100" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%"></div>';
                    fileCont.appendChild(progress);

                    var remove = document.createElement('div');
                    remove.className = "remove";
                    remove.innerHTML = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></div>';
                    list.appendChild(remove);


                }.bindToEventHandler(file));
            }
            return false;
        });
        Function.prototype.bindToEventHandler = function bindToEventHandler() {
            var handler = this;
            var boundParameters = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            //create closure
            return function (e) {
                e = e || window.event; // get window.event if e argument missing (in IE)   
                boundParameters.unshift(e);
                handler.apply(this, boundParameters);
            }
        };
    });
} else {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Your browser does not support the HTML5 FileReader.';
}


function addEventHandler(obj, evt, handler) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        // W3C method
        obj.addEventListener(evt, handler, false);
    } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        // IE method.
        obj.attachEvent('on' + evt, handler);
    } else {
        // Old school method.
        obj['on' + evt] = handler;
    }
}


//Not plugged yet
var bar = $('.progress-bar');
$(function(){
  $(bar).each(function(){
    bar_width = $(this).attr('aria-valuenow');
    $(this).width(bar_width + '%');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably had to add your own version because the existing version, per Wordpress best practices , is using `noConflict()` which removes the `$` alias.

Since you are using `$` you would have gotten errors saying `$ is undefined`.

Adding a new version can have serious implications with any plugins that are assigned to the initial version and you should only need jQuery.js loaded once.

To use in a `noConflict()` environment just wrap all of your code in:

```
(function($){
   // your code here can use `$`

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I surrounded my function with the above but it didn't work :/ I also tried removing the enqueued version 2.1.0 but then my file upload stopped working all together

Comment: important to note whatever errors get thrown in browser console. A link to live page would help also

Comment: Here is a [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/d15d4fu2n/) of the console. I noticed that the comment on the right says "Start Masonry" but that's a plugin I installed but never got around to using....

Comment: well that imagesLoaded error is a show stopper that you need to figure out

Comment: Ok I uninstalled WP Masonry plugin and now that error doesn't show up. So the issue was that plugin. But in regards to my original question - I will of course want to use other plugins in the future. They might need to use a different version of jQuery or something and throw an error in the console like the one I posted a screenshot of. How do I deal with using different versions of jQuery? Would I need to use `(function($){ // })(jQuery);` everywhere and also go into every plugin's code and make sure this surrounds all js code?

Comment: shouldn't likely need different versions. What version is site using now? Can figure it out easily in console by pasting this in `jQuery.fn.jquery` and hit enter

Comment: It says "2.1.0", no doubt because I enqueued that version from googleapis.com. But I guess I can make the argument that I will at some point need a different version. An example of this would be the js code above that I am trying to use to make a fancy file input. It doesn't seem to work when I use the built in Wordpress. but when I enqueue version 2.1.0 it works. Not sure if the same situation will arise for future plugins, but you get the idea.

Comment: but what errors were being thrown before? They were likely `$ is undefined` so you loaded a whole new version just to get `$` working again

Comment: Oh I apologize. The error was `Uncaught TypeError: $container.imagesLoaded is not a function`. When using the WP Masonry plugin, it seems to cause this error. I am toggling between activating and deactivating and that is the cause.